# When running yocto runqemu the ip seems not to be found

Tags: yocto, ros

I have built a yocto image  (just for reference see the end of this question)
when I try to run it with runqemu I get the following error:

```
runqemu - ERROR - runqemu-ifup: /opt/yocto/workspace/openembedded-core/scripts/runqemu-ifup
runqemu - ERROR - runqemu-ifdown: /opt/yocto/workspace/openembedded-core/scripts/runqemu-ifdown
runqemu - ERROR - ip: None
runqemu - ERROR - In order for this script to dynamically infer paths
 kernels or filesystem images, you either need bitbake in your PATH
 or to source oe-init-build-env before running this script.
```

I have sourced ot-init-build-env before running the script.

It seems the ip is not found. Do I need to modify `/etc/hosts` before running it?

---

The project I am using is [meta-ros](https://github.com/ros/meta-ros/wiki/OpenEmbedded-Build-Instructions)  but I am building my images inside a docker image as in [this repository](https://github.com/hubshuffle/yocto-docker-quickstart)

In [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded)  Step 5 it says

--
You start this system in the qemu virtual machine with

```
runqemu <MACHINE> core-image-ros-roscore
```

The `<MACHINE>` is the identifier that is set in the local.conf, e.g., qemux86. On the Linux virtual machine system, you can log in as root with the empty password. Now, you ensure that the own host's name in resolved by adding

```
127.0.0.1    <HOSTNAME>.localdomain        <HOSTNAME>
```

to the /etc/hosts file,

What is HOSTNAME here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is actually complaining about the "ip" command not
being found, not your IP address, you need to install it.

Depending on your distribution the package name may change, but for Ubuntu/Debian the package you need is iproute2

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install iproute2
```

Should do the trick.

Also, in case you didnt install the required packages, you may be missing a few others, you can get the list of required packages from here:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html#build-host-packages

Comment: Although my problem persists (I will post another question about it) the problem of this question is as you indicated. Thanks.

Comment: Installing manually solved the problem but this cannot be put in a dockerfile.  I wrote a question about this